# Hierarchy management solution(s)? (node or taxonomy)

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type with a large number of nodes (70K+) and have integrated a straightforward, though custom, node hierarchy solution (node reference for the parent, sibling order using delta).

I'm implementing a custom hierarchy management tool and have started out playing with taxonomy because the hierarchy management is already present (drag & drop). However, core's default taxonomy management only goes so far, and though a good starting point, will not be suitable for a vocabulary this size (moving a large piece of the tree somewhere else isn't possible, as the vocab is paginated).

I then thought about a view combo'd with VBO, and a few custom actions, but i'm not sure drag & drop could be used with this method.

**Question:**
Have you used (or seen) a drag & drop hierarchy management solution (node or taxonomy) implemented either in views or a contributed module that fits this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the wonderful [Taxonomy Manager](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) module. I don't start a big project without it these days:

> This module provides a powerful interface for managing taxonomies. A vocabulary gets displayed in a dynamic tree view, where parent terms can be expanded to list their nested child terms or can be collapsed.

It's packed with features, there's a list of them on the module page. I think this one in particular will be of interest to you:

> Double Tree interface for moving terms in hierarchies, adding new translations and switching terms between different vocabularies